# How to populate ModelAttribute from form OR session?

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, I have a `@RequestMapping` that receives a complex object as a `@ModelAttribute`.

The object comes from an HTML input form. But now I also have another use-case where I need to retain the last submitted object in the session, until the next time the form is submitted.

So, I also declared a `@SessionAttributes` with the same name.

Code:

```
@SessionAttributes("searchRequestDto")
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/test") 
public String search(@ModelAttribute SearchRequestDto searchRequestDto, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  ...
```

Unfortunately, now the value of `searchRequestDto` is coming in uninitialized (freshly instantiated), even when the form is submitted.

**TL;DR:**

How to declare the parameter so that values from a form are automatically stored and made available in the Session?

**MORE DETAILS**

The site has a complex search form (similar to airfare or hotel search, where you have to enter city, dates, class of service, etc). Any time that the user goes back to the search form, after having previously submitted a search form, regardless of whether it's the next page hit, or "N" number of page hits or "X" number of hours later, the form should be pre-filled with their last search inputs. I don't think this is a use-case for flashAttribute, suggested in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the use of `@SessionAttributes` is to call a saved `flashAttribute`.
You have not mentioned that you are using this to save the `@ModelAttribute`on form submission.
 On submission of form or when need you need to retain it use something like [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html), this will save your attributes in session for later re-use.

Comment: I don't think it's a fit for flashAttribute, I'll update the question.